# When do we consider a matrix tall and skinny?

Tags: matrices, terminology

I am using an $m \times n$ matrix that has more rows than columns, $m > n$. Namely, $m=4000$ and $n=20$. I am looking to see if it is considered as a **tall and skinny matrix** and if there is a general **formula** when we consider a matrix as Tall and Skinny matrix.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Sure, we can consider it *tall and skinny*. (We can call it whatever we like.) Now what? Formula for what?

Comment: Other than the [square matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_matrix), there isn't a standard terminology for classifying matrix dimensions by orientation or aspect ratio.  But I'm sure that most linear algebra students would readily understand the distinction between "tall and skinny" and "short and wide".  Or "vertical" and "horizontal".  Or "portrait" and "landscape".  The former tend to arise from "overdetermined" systems of equations, and the latter from "underdetermined" systems.

Comment: @Dan *long* and *wide* format are a rather standard terminology when dealing with data tables. Not sure, if this is what is meant here.

Comment: Let's say  we have a 100 x 40 , is this considered as tall and skinny ? , does the number of rows have to be a specific number bigger than the number of rows , as 60 x 40 is considered as tall and skinny ?

Comment: @abcosmoweb from physics point of view, I would say that height-to-width ratio must be much greater than 1. So 60-to-40 wouldn't do. Now, whether 3>>1 or not depends on the required error - I suppose that the error of algorithms designed for tall-and-skinny matrices scales as (w/h)^n. Just making it on the fly

Comment: @Roger Vadim thank you, i appriciate your answer.

Comment: It seems like the idea of tall and skinny is very subjective here?

Comment: What for do you need it? If it is just curiosity, the answer is: there is no official definition and you are free to call it that whenever you like. If you have a special issue where it plays a crucial role, state it.

Answer (score 0):

We usually consider a matrix as a Tall and Skinny matrix when one dimension is significantly smaller than another.

Reference:
AutoTSMM: An Auto-tuning Framework for Building High-Performance Tall-and-Skinny Matrix-Matrix Multiplication on CPUs (from [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.08088))

Comment: significantly? smaller to what degree?

Comment: In fact, there is no official definition. I think the difference in dimensions is at least two orders of magnitude (at least 10^2) is more reasonable. For example, when we convert the convolution into matrix multiplication, due to a large number of pixels in the image (10^3 times 10 ^3) and the size of the convolution kernel is small (<10), there is an optimization problem of Tall and Skinny matrix multiplication.